# Automate Printing Multiple Envelope Addresses

Tags: excel, vba, automation, word-automation, pdf-scraping

Objective: print multiple different addresses on envelopes.

I have an ETSY shop where I get order sheets in PDFs that look like in the attached. Each order has its address obviously.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvTMh.jpg)

Instead of copying and pasting each address one by one I want to automate printing those address on envelopes somehow, but I do not know how.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNJpK.jpg)

I tried docparser to scrape the address data and then I download it in an excel format, but from there I am lost.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5glp9.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGhNG.jpg)

Comment: Have you considered setting up an excel sheet with a printed area, then pasting the address data into a set of cells. Once pasted, print.

Comment: From docparser expor it to excel, from there you can can do a mail merge (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)

Comment: Best Way I've found is to use label stickers. It's REALLY easy once you get the hang of it. You build your list in excel, then open a word doc, You'll need to select the right label size... then [HERE is the tutorial I used](https://www.howtogeek.com/413665/how-to-create-mailing-labels-in-word-from-an-excel-list/)